# Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT with Gson and Retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit2, gson

My app try to consume an API using `Retrofit` and `Gson`.

My request is to `https://nahuatiliztli.herokuapp.com/laws.json` and it returns back:

```
[{"id":1,"title":"Constitución Política de los Estados Unidos Mexicanos","url":"http://www.diputados.gob.mx/LeyesBiblio/pdf/1_29ene16.pdf","created_at":"2016-07-10T02:36:00.641Z","updated_at":"2016-07-10T02:36:00.641Z"}]
```

My code is structured as follow…

My model is `Law` class:

```
public class Law {
    @SerializedName("id")
    private Integer mId;
    @SerializedName("title")
    private String mTitle;
    @SerializedName("url")
    private String mUrl;

    public Law(Integer id, String title, String url) {
        mId = id;
        mTitle = title;
        mUrl = url;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return mId;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        mId = id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return mTitle;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        mTitle = title;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return mUrl;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        mUrl = url;
    }
}
```

My response abstraction is `LawsResponse` class:

```
public class LawsResponse {
    private List<Law> mLaws;

    public List<Law> getLaws() {
        return mLaws;
    }

    public void setLaws(List<Law> laws) {
        mLaws = laws;
    }
}
```

My service interface for `Law` model is:

```
public interface LawsService {
    @GET("https://nahuatiliztli.herokuapp.com/laws.json")
    Call<LawsResponse> listLaws();
}
```

My adapter is `LawsApiAdapter`:

```
public class LawsApiAdapter {

    private static LawsService API_SERVICE;

    public static LawsService getInstance() {
        if (API_SERVICE==null) {
            Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(Constants.BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(buildLawsApiGsonConverter()))
                    .build();

            API_SERVICE = retrofit.create(LawsService.class);
        }

        return API_SERVICE;
    }

    private static Gson buildLawsApiGsonConverter() {
        return new GsonBuilder()
                .registerTypeAdapter(
                        LawsApiAdapter.class,
                        new LawsDeserializer())
                .create();
    }

}
```

I have tried many suggestions posted in this site but it still throwing this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2 path $
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2 path $
```

I understand by reading many posts that it is expecting a Json object and it is receiving a Json array, indeed that I want, but I do not how to make it works yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LawsResponse is not required. Update your interface

```
public interface LawsService {
    @GET("https://nahuatiliztli.herokuapp.com/laws.json")
    Call<List<Law>> listLaws();
}
```

And you can add your retrofit request as follows:

```
Call<List<Law>> call = LawsApiAdapter.getInstance().listLaws();
call.enqueue(this);//pass your callback instance
```

In Your Activity :

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity implements Callback<List<Law>>{

//your rest of methods

@Override
    public void onResponse(Call<List<Law>> call, Response<List<Law>> response) {
        List<Law> lawlist = response.body();
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<List<Law>> call, Throwable t) {

        Log.i("log", "exhibits api error : " + t.getLocalizedMessage());

    }

    private void loadLawList(){
Call<List<Law>> call = LawsApiAdapter.getInstance().listLaws();
call.enqueue(this);//pass your callback instance
    }
}
```

Call loadLawList method when you want to load data.